# elasticsearch 1.3+ and secure scripts workflow

Tags: elasticsearch

I've upgraded to Elasticsearch 1.3.x and by default dynamic scripting is disabled for security reasons. The advice is now to place any used scripts as a file in config/scripts directory. My question is how to integrate this into a multi-user production environment? Each developer needs to have it installed, the circleci needs it, I have to ensure the search cluster connected to Heroku has it. Is there anyway I can integrate this into our git workflow? (Info on the new security setup: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/scripting-security/)